# Write Only Memory Mapping in boost?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, memory-mapped-files

Why doesn't boost interprocess support write only memory mapping?

Maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't a write only mapping be significantly faster than a read/write mapping as the OS doesn't have to read in the pages from the disk, just flush out pages from memory to the disk? Also it would have the benefit of being entirely non blocking (except for flushing and destruction).

Would I benefit by switching from boost to native OS memory mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact if you allocate a new memory-mapped file of size, say, 20Gb, you'll get a sparse file allocation of that size.

When "mapping in" pages of that files, there need to be a read operation (as the OS might be able to tell that the page is not physically present yet on disk), and only when (if) those pages are dirtied need they be written out.

Of course, this is implementation dependent and I don't think POSIX (can) guarantee this, but it's not unreasonable behaviour IYAM, and would be the equivalent of write-only mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a write-only memmap would not be faster, as the OS can only keep track of changes / provide those mappings in whole-page granularity.

At least, if you want to avoid the prohibitive cost of simulating all access to such pages in kernel-land (not implemented) instead of just mapping a page.

Somehow, I doubt going directly to the OS API instead of going through the Boost-API could provide any significant speed-ups:

The boost API is a thin wrapper over the OS-specific interface and will be completely inlined and thus compiled out by any decent compiler.

Comment: The reason I was considering the OS API was because it allows for write only mapping. Though, I was unsure if that has any practical difference.

Comment: Not sure what whole page increments has to to with the difference between write only and read/write?

Comment: Your question asks whether going for write-only mapping of a file would be faster, and that is important for the answer. Hm.. *granularity*  would be better there.

Comment: @Depuplicator: I'm still not following? What does page increments have to do with it? The OS will work on page size increments regardless if it is write only or read/write?

Comment: The OS works in page granularity for keeping track of those changes / providing memory.

Comment: Yes, and and how does that differ between write only and read/write?

Comment: It explains why a write-only mapping does not have any speed advantage over a read-write mapping (for all but anonymous memory ;-))